# Problem with generic array initialization in java

Tags: java, class, generics, casting

I am working with a generic type `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, and want to create an array of the same.

I tried this approach :

```
T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[length]
```

But the code breaks with `ClassCastException : class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable`.

Of course, I can instantiate it using a class that implements `Comparable`. For example:

```
T[] arr = (T[]) new Integer[length]
```

But this would kill the purpose of my code. Does anyone know any workarounds?

Comment: How about `new Comparable[length]`?

Comment: Why do you need it? Usually the functions that accept a `Comparable` also provide an overload that takes a generic object as well as a `Comparator` .

Comment: @Sweeper your solution works, but why? I did not try it before because I thought we cannot instantiate interfaces using the new keyword! (I am a student and not very well aware of the intricacies of the Java language)

Comment: You are not instantiating an interface. You are instantiating an array, which can contain instances of classes that implement `Comparable`.

Comment: do not confuse `new Comparable` and `new Comparable[]` - first is creating (or trying to create) an instance of that interface; second is creating an instance of an array for elements of that type (no instance of that type is created yet)